# More elegant way to write this C# loop code?

Tags: c#, .net, coding-style

I have to do these kinds of initializations all over for different members:

```
this.Effects = new Effect [ image.Effects ];
for ( int i = 0; i < image.NumEffects; ++i )
{
    this.Effects [ i ] = new Effect ( image.Effects [ i ] );
}
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Like this:

```
this.Effects = Array.ConvertAll(image.Effects, e => new Effect(e));
```

This will be faster than the equivalent LINQ calls with `Select` and `ToArray` which will probably be answered shortly after this.

Comment: Thanks, you are amazing. Didn't know you can do this.

Comment: Mine says, has invalid arguments. Is it because image.Effects is of type IList<IEffect>? and have no .Count, has .NumEffects? That's why my higher level type is wrapping this image.Effects.

Comment: @Joan: This only works for arrays.  If you have an `IList<Effect>`, you'll need to use LINQ.

Answer (score 5):

Linq would be something like this:

```
this.Effects = image.Effects.Select(x => new Effect(x)).ToArray();
```

Answer (score 5):

Or use the `Parallel.For` to use multiple threads.

Comment: That's interesting. I will give this a try.

Comment: Unless the `Effect` constructor is very slow, that won't be worth it.

Comment: Well it depends on your definition of 'elegant'